# Finding objects using scala's runtime reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

### Context

I use scala 2.11.6 currently, possibly 2.11.7 in the future.
Given compiled class files in the classpath, I want to do 2 things:

- Find the name of any objects that implements a certain interface:

  ```
  trait Service
  trait ServiceFactory {
    def create(): Service
  }
  ...
  package my.package
  object MyServiceFactory extends ServiceFactory {
    def create(): Service = new Service()
  }
  ```

  Here the name would be something like `my.package.MyServiceFactory` as it implements the `ServiceFactory` trait.
- Given the fully qualified name of the object I want to get the reference to the object's instance.

  ```
  val factory = getInstance[ServiceFactory]("my.package.MyServiceFactory")
  val service = factory.create()
  ```

### Problem

The problem to both scenarios is verifying the type inheritance and *making sure it is a singleton object*.
Checking the class seems straight-forward but given all the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors$RuntimeMirror)
I could understand, none helped me implementing something like `isSingletonObject(name: String): Boolean` as used in:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(classLoader)

def getInstance[T](name: String)(implicit tt: ru.TypeTag[T]): T = {
  if (!isSingletonObject(name)) throw new RuntimeException(
    s"$name does not specify a singleton object")
  val moduleSym = try rm.staticModule(name).asModule
  if (!(moduleSym.moduleClass.asClass.selfType <:< tt.tpe))
      throw new RuntimeException("Type of loaded module " + moduleSym.fullName
        + " does not satisfy subtype relationship with "
        + tt.tpe.typeSymbol.fullName)
  val mm = rm.reflectModule(moduleSym.asModule)
  mm.instance.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

How can one find objects and verify that a given name is really an object?
Alternative approaches to the given scenarios are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you could use [ClassUtil library](http://software.clapper.org/classutil/#finding_classes_at_runtime). Note that it'll find Java classes, and the ones which correspond to `object`s will have names ending in `$class`. See also [Scala Reflection - Loading or finding classes based on trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490779/scala-reflection-loading-or-finding-classes-based-on-trait).

For the second, `object`s [are called "modules"](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors$ModuleMirror) in Scala reflection, so you don't need `isSingletonObject(name)`; if it isn't, `rm.staticModule(name).asModule` in your code will fail. There doesn't seem to be a way to check if it's a compiler-generated empty companion object (`isSynthetic` returns false), but they will be ruled out by the subtyping check anyway (so will the static parts of Java classes, but you can also filter those out using `isJava`).

Comment: So you suggest to just do the reflection and check for exceptions?

Comment: For the second question, yes. See the edited answer for the first.

Comment: Thanks. I found a similiar [class path scanning](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library and use to get a list of names. Concerning the objects, it seems there is no proper way to make sure it is a scala object, maybe because jvm has no special support for scala?
Anyway I scan for all classes that have the trait and use only the modules.It also makes no difference whether I use `MyServiceFactory` or `MyServiceFactory$` both refer seemingly to the same object instance when reflected using scala.

Comment: "it seems there is no proper way to make sure it is a scala object, maybe because jvm has no special support for scala" As mentioned in the answer, symbols have an `isJava` method.