# Where should the META-INF/services be in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Where should the META-INF directory be in order for sbt to pick up custom configurations. I had this issue when trying to use the ServiceLoader and I was trying to create a custom services in META-INF/services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The META-INF folder will get automatically picked up by sbt if you put the folder in src/main/resources/

Comment: Note that if you're using the playframework it messes with the classpath and it seems like this does not work in development mode or the console, nor does putting it into the conf directory make a difference. I haven't figure'd out how to get a service loader to work with play yet but figure'd I would comment for anyone who gets here like I did looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

For Play application code the META-INF should be put inside the conf directory inside service/conf

I have verified this on my own application where I used it for putting META-INF/services/ file with the name of api.ImplementationClass in it and it worked with ServiceLoader.load