# Protecting fields from Reflection - The strange case of the System.security

Tags: java, security, reflection

I am currently looking into java security and came across a strange phenomenon. The SecurityManager in java is stored in the field "security" in java.lang.System. Interestingly, the field seems to be protected against reflective access, which does make sense, but as far as I know this field is the only one which is. So here is the example:

```
for(Field f : System.class.getDeclaredFields())
    System.out.println(f);
```

outputs

```
public static final java.io.InputStream java.lang.System.in
public static final java.io.PrintStream java.lang.System.out
public static final java.io.PrintStream java.lang.System.err
private static volatile java.io.Console java.lang.System.cons
private static java.util.Properties java.lang.System.props
private static java.lang.String java.lang.System.lineSeparator
```

Interestingly: the field declared as

```
private static volatile SecurityManager security = null;
```

is not in the list, and sure enough a call to

```
System.class.getDeclaredField("security");
```

yields a NoSuchFieldException. As I couldn't find anything about this online, and I am pretty sure this field used to be accessible via reflection (see also, for example, this [blog post](http://slightlyrandombrokenthoughts.blogspot.de/2010/02/java-se-security-part-iii-keys.html) from 2010 which describes accessing this field) I was wondering a) was this implemented as a quick fix to prevent easily disabling the securitymanager via reflection and b) how this is implemented (or rather is there any chance of protecting other private fields from reflection as well).

Comment: If I recall correctly, this field being unaccessible is the result of a patch introduced to close a security hole in Java applets. Not 100% sure.

Comment: That would indeed be interesting because there are a couple of different ways to disable the securitymanager if one has reflection..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colleague pointed out that the answer is not in the jvm but in the jdk, more precisely in the class sun.reflect.Reflection. There you'll find a static initializer that does the following

```
static {
    Map<Class,String[]> map = new HashMap<Class,String[]>();
    map.put(Reflection.class,
        new String[] {"fieldFilterMap", "methodFilterMap"});
    map.put(System.class, new String[] {"security"});
    fieldFilterMap = map;

    methodFilterMap = new HashMap<Class,String[]>();
}
```

If we now look a bit closer at the getDeclaredFields method in java.lang.Class we'll find that the fields are filtered using a call to the Reflection class:

```
Reflection.filterFields(this, getDeclaredFields0(publicOnly));
```

where filterFields is implemented as

```
public static Field[] filterFields(Class containingClass,
                                   Field[] fields) {
    if (fieldFilterMap == null) {
        // Bootstrapping
        return fields;
    }
    return (Field[])filter(fields, fieldFilterMap.get(containingClass));
}
```

So .. this solves the issue how the field is protected. I am however still curious as to why this was implemented.

Comment: Nice find, +1. Where are you getting the source for the `sun.*` classes? Or are you just using a really nice decompiler?

Comment: You can get the code as a download package from http://openjdk.java.net/. There you'll also find a tutorial on how to check out the mercurial repository.

Answer (score -1):

First, the way this was prevented from reflection was probably a dirty `if` in the JVM under the field getting mechanism:

```
if (strcmp(field, "security") == 0 && strcmp(class, "java.lang.System")) {
    return NULL;
```

(I am NOT meaning to imply that this is the actual code in the JVM!!)

This obviously is not accesible to most users of java, so the only other option is to install a security manager that disallows private field and method access. This is possible, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Denying private field and method access via a SecurityManager is possible by not giving the permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks". However, that this is "fixed" in the jvm seems to be a very crude hack. Do you know of any documentation?

Comment: This seems not to be the case. At least a quick search for "security" in the hotspot vm sources does not trigger anything like it.

Comment: @acerberus Hotspot VM? That is not the JVM, it is the just-in-time compiler. It would not be found there. I don't know of any documentation showing this, this is just the only way I can think of.