# Find all classes availible at runtime java

Tags: java, jvm, guava

I am attempting to find the names of all classes available at runtime in Java and have had some success using reflection in Guava with code such as:

```
ClassPath classPath = ClassPath.from(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
contextClasses = classPath.getAllClasses();
```

This appears to work to some extent getting me about 2500 class names, however it does not find all of them, in particular the java.lang, java.util, etc. classes which i really do need to know about.

Is there a different class loader I should be using for this?  I have also tried

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Ewen

## Further detail about solution.

I used further information from this post: [How can I list all classes loaded in a specific class loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681459/how-can-i-list-all-classes-loaded-in-a-specific-class-loader) to actually implement the solution suggested in the answer.  This seams to get all of the standard java libraries (some 500 ish) but not the ones I go in my method previously.  I could combine with the previous to get everything I need.

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: try using java instrumentation framework, it won't disappoint you.

Comment: system classes are loaded by bootstrap class loader, it is null e.g. java.lang.String.class.getClassLoader()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a post 1.5 JVM, you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses().