# Getting a list of all the bootstrap classes on the JVM?

Tags: java, classloader

There is a method called `findBootstrapClass` for a ClassLoader that returns a Class if it is bootstrapped. Is there a way to find  classes has been loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to first get the bootstrap class loader by e.g. calling

```
ClassLoader bootstrapLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent();
```

and then get the classes of this class loader as explained here: [How can I list all classes loaded in a specific class loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681459/how-can-i-list-all-classes-loaded-in-a-specific-class-loader).

But note, that getting the bootstrap class loader is not reliable, because it may not explicitly exist. So `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent()` may return null, as explained in the Javadoc of [ClassLoader#getParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html):

> Returns the parent class loader for delegation. Some implementations
>   may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will
>   return null in such implementations if this class loader's parent is
>   the bootstrap class loader.

Comment: On most implementations between Java 2 and Java 8, inclusive, the expression `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent()` will give you the *extension class loader*, so you would have to use `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent().getParent()` to get the bootstrap loader, though, it would be much simpler to use `Object.class.getClassLoader()`, as if not `java.lang.Object` has been loaded through the bootstrap loader, what else should have been? But, well, I don’t know any environment where the bootstrap loader is not represented by `null`…