# Is there a Java equivalent to PHP's get_declared_classes()?

Tags: java, php, class, object, instantiation

I'm looking for a way to print all instantiated Objects in Java. There's an easy way with PHP using [get_declared_classes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php):

```
<?php
print_r(get_declared_classes());
?>
```

Is there an equivalent in Java, that works just as easy as in PHP?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaringclass.htm
That should help you out,

Comment: @user3122479 he needs complete list

Comment: another way is Keep track of them while you instantiate them

Comment: This is an interesting requirement. I don't think there's a great way to do this in Java. I honestly don't even think the PHP version will work very well looking at its implementation - it's going to miss things. If you only care about certain objects I'd do what Shailendra Sharma suggested and just keep track of them as you make them. Otherwise I wouldn't trust any code to do this reliably without substantial effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I did a little research myself and found out that for debugging purposes the easiest way is to start the JVM with the command line option `-verbose:class` like this:

```
java -verbose:class Example
```

It's going to list all instantiated classes and that does the job for me. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Loading classes in Java is done via class loaders, so you can only ever hope to get all classes loaded by a given class loader. Note that one class can possibly be loaded by different class loaders and that it can even be loaded in different versions by different class loaders.

If you want to find out which classes have been loaded by a single class loader, check out [How can I list all classes loaded in a specific class loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681459/how-can-i-list-all-classes-loaded-in-a-specific-class-loader)

A simple solution might be

```
Field f = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("classes");
f.setAccessible(true);

Vector<Class> classes =  (Vector<Class>) f.get(classLoader);
```

But this depends on Suns implementation and might fail with other vendors.