# Iterating through all JDK classes

Tags: java, reflection, classpath

I'm making a code editor and I'm working on the autocomplete. I want to programmatically get a list of all the classes that come with the JDK.

Examples include:

```
java.io.File
java.util.ArrayList
javax.swing.Action
```

I've found ways to get classes for a specific package. For instance, I can get all classes that start with `com.mypackage.foo`. The problem is that I'm trying to get classes that were loaded with the `Bootstrap ClassLoader`. And on the OSX JDK, that classloader shows up as `null`. For instance, if I do `String.class.getClassLoader()`, that is `null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681459/how-can-i-list-all-classes-loaded-in-a-specific-class-loader) might help.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one when I was searching google for hours lol.  Don't want to do instrumentation because it's hacky and requires giving JVM args.  The bottom "hackerish" solution only gives classes that have already been loaded. So when I ran it it only showed 2 classes, not thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open rt.jar with java.util.jar.JarFile and iterate over its entries. This is how can get URL to rt.jar : `URL url = Object.class.getResource("String.class");`

Comment: How does my program know where rt.jar is located?  I want this to work on all OS's and all computers, not just mine.

Comment: the getResource(String.class) way of doing it seems to work well. That gives the path to the jar. So i'll use that to index all the classes. Thanks!