# How to list all Java packages and classes/types from all dependencies including the JDK for a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

How can I list all Java packages and types from ALL dependencies including the used JDK for a maven project? I know only of listing a dependency tree or list of the maven packages but I am talking about Java package names.

This is helpful for detecting conflicts like types from JDK11 and dependencies from the pom.xml.

I did not find any tool yet and had to look into all dependencies in the IDE manually to find all Java packages and types provided.

Some maven plugin would be really useful.

Comment: [how about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2681509/592355), [or this](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java/list-all-files-in-resouce-folder.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found [jboss-tattletale](https://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.2/en-US/html_single/) useful for this kind of thing in the past. Unfortunately it hasn't been updated in years. It does help with non-JVM classes still.

Maven Enforcer's [Extra Enforcer Rules](https://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html) has code to fail the build if duplicate classes are found.

Neither of these do exactly what you want, but they might be good starting points to build something.